# JavaScript jQuery find value SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, find

I am getting the error `Error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id` on this line below, and I cannot work out why.

I have a form with an ID of `dform`, I have a radio button with a name of `del_standard_use_b_as_s` and i'd like to get the value of it.

```
var std_address_copy = $('#dform').find('input[name=del_standard_use_b_as_s]').val();
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Can you give us more code ? Did you check in debug that $ is jquery ?

Comment: Lines before this code are more important than the lines after this one.

Comment: Does it help when you add double quotes around "del_standard_use_b_as_s"

Comment: The code shown is correct. We need more information to help you out.

Comment: I'm using jQuery validate to validate the form when it is submitted, so I have `$('#dform).validate({` just before this line.

Comment: @JScoobyCed The doc states this is unneeded : "An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string"

Comment: @crmpicco can you show code for validate function

Comment: @crmpicco It sounds like you are missing a `:` in an object declaration. Without more code, it is hard to tell where, but I would start to look in your declaration of `.validate({...})`, if that is what you do just prior to this line, and look for a missing `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the previous line is

```
$('#dform).validate({
```

then I guess the problems comes from the fact that validate should be passed options

From the doc ( http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate ), assuming your code is part of the submitHandler, something like :

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
         var std_address_copy = $('#dform').find('input[name=del_standard_use_b_as_s]').val();
    ....
   }
})
```

Hope this will help